# How to convert DNAbin to FASTA in R?

Tags: r, fasta

I am trying to convert DNAbin files to fasta format. Rationale: I want to use the fasta file to calculate non-synonymous/synonymous mutation rate.

`my_dnabin1` is a DNAbin file of 55 samples and I am using the following code to convert it into a fasta file.

`dnabin_to_fasta <- lapply(my_dnabin1, function(x) as.character(x[1:length(x)]))`
This generates a list of 55 samples which looks like:

$SS.11.01

[1] "t" "t" "a" "c" "c" "t" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "g" "c" "c" "g" "c" "t" "t" "c" "c" "c" "t" "c" "c" "a" "a"
 [27] "c" "c" "c" "t" "a" "g" "a" "a" "g" "c" "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "t" "t" "t" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c" "c" "a"

$SS.11.02

[1] "t" "t" "a" "c" "c" "t" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "g" "c" "c" "g" "c" "t" "t" "c" "c" "c" "t" "c" "c" "a" "a"
 [27] "c" "c" "c" "t" "a" "g" "a" "a" "g" "c" "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "t" "t" "t" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c" "c" "a"

and so on...

However, I want a fasta formatted file as the output that may look something like:

`>SS.11.01 ttacctga`

`>SS.11.02 ttacctga`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
cat(file="out.fa", paste(paste0(">",names(dnabin_to_fasta)),
          sapply(dnabin_to_fasta, paste, collapse=""), sep="\n"), sep="\n");
```

A bit of explanation, starting from the middle outwards:

1. Collapse the letter arrays inside dnabin_to_fasta into single strings
2. Append ">" to the front of the names of each sequence
3. Concatenate the results of steps 1 & 2 together, separating with a line break
4. Write each concatenated string to a file, separating by a line break

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved a major part of my problem. When I print it to the screen, I get the exact output I want. However, it does not produce any output files. Could you please help me with this, too?

Comment: Note that R will save files in the "working directory", which is not necessarily the directory that the last file was loaded from. If you're using `cat` with the `file` option, it's probably saving *somewhere*. You can find out where by using the `getwd()` command.

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my problem! I was stuck in it since a long time.